# Application location downloaded from store in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, gaming

I have downloaded a couple of games from the Windows store, but I can't find their  folder location anywhere on my computer. Both of them show up at the start menu and I can use them too, but neither me or my game booster can pinpoint them on the computer hard disk.

I can find no such folder with the name "Windows Applications" or "Applications", does this have anything to do with my deactivated OS version?

I have checked out both of the Program Files and Program Files(x86) folders with no luck.

Comment: What is a "game booster"? Is this some sort of cheat tool?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10 you can find the location of your apps here:

`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`

This is a hidden folder, so from your explorer window go to **View** and tick the **Hidden items** option.

---

**Access the folder**

You will not be able at first to access the folder. Do the following:

- Right click on the folder and go to **Properties**.
- Go to the **Security** tab and click **Advanced**.
- At the top of the window at **Owner** click change and set your user (be sure to have admin rights on that user).

Now it will prompt you one more time when trying to access your folder, but after you click Continue it will let you in.

Comment: Unless you want to break every UWP I don't suggest changing the ownership of the folder though

Comment: Sorry for bugging you again, ik i am dumb, but after clicking CHANGE and typing the admin password, it is asking me to SELECT USER OR GROUP and asks me to fill up a space with the heading ENTER THE OBJECT NAME TO SELECT, I have no idea what this is about

Comment: @ZippyParakeet  There you type your username and click on Check Names, then OK.