# Where is this icon located in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, icons

Where is this icon: [image: Icon] located in Windows 10?

I tried searching in `imageres.dll`, `shell32.dll` and `wmploc.dll` using **Resource Hacker**, but couldn't find it there. I need a higher resolution (as much as possible) version of this icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Location**

That's the `Photos` app icon. You can find it at the following location as a .png file (multiple variations):

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_17.425.10010.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Assets\
```

---

**Access Folder**

To have access to the **WindowsApps** folder follow the instructions I have provided to another question here: https://superuser.com/a/1205874/552853

---

**Direct Download**

In case you don't want to make changes and just want this icon here you go:

*(the highest resolution is 336x336)*

[image]

Comment: That's it, what I'm looking for. Thank you so much, buddy.  @User552853